# Google map API JS get localization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I need your help please,
I have a website and i need to add localization map in my website and get the localization user from it, how can i do it,
thanks,

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question, and requests for libraries and resources are generally on topic. This is probably very easily Googled, though. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "localization map" - if it's just a map of a certain address, I bet `angularjs google map` will get you great results. If you need to localize the device user, see Craicerjack's link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting localization in Javascript is easily done within the browser or within the Google Map API.

The Browser GeoLocation can be used to determine location based on location services within the browser.  Instructions with code examples can be found at the [Mozilla Developer Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

For using the Google Maps API you can view their documentation at their [tutorials page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

I actually use a combination of the two to return city/county/state for a user for a weather app that I put together.  The entire code can be found at my [GitHub page](https://github.com/davidtaylorjr/local-weather-webapp) but here is the code for GeoLocation.

```
function geoLocation() {
    var output = document.getElementById("out");

    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;



        //Google Maps API to return printed location as opposed to lat/lon coordinates.


        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&key=YOUR-API-KEY', function(city) {


            var address = city.results[2].formatted_address;
```

After that you can use whatever you want with the data.

Comment: thank you, that what i looking for, i find too [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

Comment: @BadrKenzallah Great, let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: thank you for your help (y)